# Gibt es Wörter, bei denen noch ein Trema verwendet wird?

Tags: punctuation

Wikipedia sagt zum Trema, dass es in der neuen Rechtschreibung gar nicht behandelt wird.

Gibt es Wörter, bei denen das Trema noch regelmäßig verwendet wird?

Comment: +1 weil es zu schön wäre, aber −1 weil die Antwort enttäuschend ist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nach der *"amtlichen Regelung der deutschen Rechtschreibung vom März 2006"* sind diakritische Zeichen nur noch auf den Umlauten ä,ö und ü vorgesehen.

Ein Trema ist somit im deutschen Alphabet und somit auch in deutschen Wörten nicht vorhanden.

Allerdings werden diakritische Zeichen in Fremdwörtern und Eigennamen übernommen, wie zum Beispiel bei *Anaïs Nin* oder *Citroën*.

Comment: Ich würde die Alëuten stets mit Trema schreiben.

Comment: Die *Aleutian Islands* werden in den USA ebenfalls ohne `ë` geschrieben, im Duden heißt es *Aleuten* - ohne Trema.

Comment: Das mag sein, ich würde es aber trotzdem mit Trema schreiben. Es sind eben nicht die _Aloiten_.

Comment: Viele schreiben im Englischen natürlich generell ohne Trema - andere, wie zum Beispiel Raymond Chen, verwenden es (z.B. coöperation). Ist dort aber wohl auch eher am Aussterben.

Comment: Es gibt auch einige, die naïv mit Trema schreiben.

Comment: Ein paar Gedanken hatte ich dazu noch, die aber zu umfangreich für einen Kommentar hier waren, daher habe ich sie als Antwort verfasst. Aufgrund der schön kurz gefassten Aussage gebe ich hier auch noch +1.

Comment: Das <_i_> hat ja sowieso schon einen Punkt, aber auch das <_e_> gibt es im Deutschen mit einem diakritischen Zeichen, nämlich den aus dem Französischen übernommenen Akut `´`. Interessanterweise ist dessen Standardumschrift dieselbe wie bei den Umlauten: ein angehängtes <_e_>, also <_Attaché_> → <_Atta(s)chee_>. Mit weitem Abstand am häufigsten kommt es in _Café_ und dessen Komposita vor (vermutlich weil es sich wegen _Kaffee_ einer Eindeutschung erfolgreich widersetzt).

Answer (score 6):

Auch vor der Rechtschreibreform wurde meines Wissens das Trema nicht in amtlichen Regelwerken behandelt (die amtliche Rechtschreibung vor der letzten Reform riet von einer Verwendung lediglich ab). Schon im 19. Jahrhundert wurde beschlossen (Quelle findet sich gerade nicht wieder - habe es aber kürzlich gelesen), dass Umlaute nur noch durch die zwei Punkte gekennzeichnet werden und somit nicht mehr mit folgendem e geschrieben werden dürfen, wodurch die Buchstabenfolgen ae, oe und ue automatisch mehrsilbig wurden und es somit keines Tremas mehr bedarf (z.B. Aerodynamik). Konsequenterweise bedürfte auch der bekannte Name Citroën keines Tremas im Deutschen - hier wird es jedoch verwendet, weil es sich um einen Eigennamen handelt. Die Schreibweise Citroen würde im Deutschen aber ebenso ausgesprochen werden - hier stößt man nur auf Probleme, wenn aus irgendeinem Grund Umlaute nicht verwendet werden können (z.B. technische Probleme) - aber dann kann man vermutlich auch kein Trema schreiben.

Ansonsten wurde oder wird ein Trema nur noch angewendet, um Missverständnisse auszuschließen - auch bei Eigennamen jedoch nur über i oder e, um eine Verwechslung mit den deutschen Umlauten, die dasselbe diakritische Zeichen verwenden, zu vermeiden. Das früher mit Trema geschriebene Ai (ein Faultier) steht aber im Duden heute auch nur noch mit einfachem i. Insofern sind mir keine Wörter mit Trema außer Eigennamen bekannt, die natürlich häufig einer anderen Sprache entspringen. Bei diesen aber muss man ohnehin wissen, wie sie ausgesprochen werden.

Comment: ＋１ für die „automatische Mehrsilbigkeit“, wobei diese sich – bei verbotenem Trema – auch auf andere Buchstabenfolgen beziehen müsste (etwa *ai* in *naiv/Ukraine* weil *naïve/Україна*).